# mongodb most efficient way to store gps tracking data

Tags: mongodb

I need to store gps points (timestamp, lon, lat) from different users.

should I have a separate users collection and a gps data collection:

users

```
{_id: 1, name: 'A'}
```

gps

```
{_id: 1, userId: 1, timestamp: ..., lon: ..., lat: ...}
{_id: 2, userId: 1, timestamp: ..., lon: ..., lat: ...}
```

or can I just save the gps data as an array into the corresponding user document:

users

```
{_id: 1, name: 'A', gps: [
     {timestamp: ..., lon: ..., lat: ...}
     {timestamp: ..., lon: ..., lat: ...}
]}
```

I know that option 2 would be crazy for SQL DBs, but I am not sure about the performance implications with MongoDB

Comment: MongoDB requires location data to be in either array format of longitude, latitude `[lon,lat]` or in GeoJSON format e.g `{ "type": "Point", "coordinates": [lon,lat] }` in order to be valid for use with geospatial queries if that is a concern. It would probably be best to store that way as a matter of good practice even if you do not want geospatial queries.

Answer (score 4):

You must design your MongoDB collections based on the **access strategy** of your application.

In general, you should go for embedding points into user doc if:

- embedded data (points) are always retrieved when user info are
  retrieved. If you are always retrieving user info but rarely you need also GPS data then embedding cannot be so good.
- embedded data are not subject to modifications (or at least rarely)
- the cardinality is not too big (remember MongoDB document max size
  is 16MB). If you have 100K points per user split the collections

Furthermore, having points embedded into user docs, you can take advantage of
document level locking (if you are using Wired Tiger storage engine). Otherwise, if you're in a concurrent system, with the two collections design you have to handle locking mechanism by yourself at application level.